# Templates & Resources for creating documentation using Azure DevOps Wiki

Tags: azure-devops, documentation

Working on a relatively new team in a much larger organization, and as a side project I am looking at our current documentation for opportunities to improve/standardize our best practices/standards. The ideal tool we would like to use, if up to the task, is Azure DevOps Wiki (this is AZDO Service, not Server) since it lines up with the rest of our PM functions. I was doing some digging, and I have not found much in the way of resources/templates/guides that can really get you going for Azure DevOps Wiki.

Beyond general documentation best practices, is there any helpful tricks/resources that we can use to make the most out of that particular tool? Or is there just a better tool we should consider? Looking for ideas! Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Here are the documents: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/about-readme-wiki?view=azure-devops, do you have any specific question?

Comment: I appreciate it! I see the documentation which identifies on a 'broad' level what can be done. What I am looking for is a library of templates/resources that could be used to help standardize documentation. Also hoping to hear from other people who have used the Wiki in their own production environments and how they made the most of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am looking for is a library of templates/resources that could
> be used to help standardize documentation.

**Official doesn't provided any template or resources for standard.** There has been a feature request here:

[Make it possible to create wiki page based on a template](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/make-it-possible-to-create-wiki-page-based-on-a-te/365866)

You can upvote this feature request of Azure DevOps and share your ideas.

But since the DevOps wiki is designed based on Azure DevOps repository, you can clone the template you want to your wiki repository.

The repository url of your wiki should be:

`https://dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/<Project Name>/_git/<Project Name>.wiki`

Use this command to clone the wiki repository:

`git clone https://<Personal Access Token>@dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/<Project Name>/_git/<Project Name>.wiki`

## PS:

Every DevOps project has a hidden repository, which named **'`<Project Name>.wiki`'**, this repository can't be access via the repository UI list, also can't be listed via the **[List Repositories REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP)**. This repository also unable to be managed as other common repositories. Only '**Security for Wiki**'. The repository will store all of the information in the pages of wiki permanently unless you delete the file in the repo.

And the comments section of the wiki is implemented [quite differently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/add-comments-wiki?view=azure-devops#add-a-comment), it is not based on a git repo and does not provide an explicit manage method. If you accidentally delete an image in a comment from the wiki, you won't have any way to get it back.